# shellinabox on arch linux

Tags: systemd

I cannot get the systemd service to run

```
[chris@alarmpi shellinabox]$ sudo systemctl status shellinaboxd
* shellinaboxd.service - Serve a login-terminal over http on port 80
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/shellinaboxd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 24 22:20:57 alarmpi systemd[1]:[/usr/lib/systemd/system/shellinaboxd.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'Required' in section 'Unit'
Jul 24 22:22:10 alarmpi systemd[1]:[/usr/lib/systemd/system/shellinaboxd.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'Required' in section 'Unit'
Jul 24 22:24:55 alarmpi systemd[1]:[/usr/lib/systemd/system/shellinaboxd.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'Required' in section 'Unit'
```

Here is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Serve a login-terminal over http on port 80
Required=sshd.service
After=sshd.service

[Service]
User=chris
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/shellinaboxd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/shellinaboxd  $SHELLINABOXD_ARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for *`Requires`* or *`RequiredBy`*. Don't worry about getting that stuff right the first time - `systemd` syntax is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required is not a valid directive.  You might mean either `Requires` or `RequiredBy`.  The directives are enumerated in the man page for systemd.directives(7).

Comment: `Requiredby` did the trick. Thank you